# Plugging in voice chat within php based web application

Tags: discord, chat, skype, voice

I have a web based game application that is built using php. When players play a match, I want them to be able to talk to each other. What is the best way to achieve this?
I checked out Discord, but to use it effectively, I have to create a new channel for every match and get those users into this channel. Once inside Discord they should not have access to other channels that are created for other matches. Is this achievable through Discord?

Or is there another API that is better for my requirement?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Performing actions as a specific user in discord is impossible unless you have their user token, and in that case its against Discord TOS, as its considered self-botting.

Comment: ok..wondering what is the next best option then. Is Zoom API a good solution for this?